# Break-Down Data in Excel without VBA (Formula Only)

Tags: excel

Many times, I am required to provide some type of break-down to the customers - an example is shown in the attached figure.

I have a table of data ("TABLE DATA" - which is some type of pivot) + Customer provides its official form, its structure must be preserved (highlighted in yellow ). Basically, I need to separate the cost details of CODE "A" and CODE "B" into 2 separated sections.

Customer requires me to provided details for each individual Part (example shows Part A - "Break-Down Part A)

Is there anyway to put a"ITEM" from "TABLE DATA" into Code A and Code B ? the rests can be solved by Vlookup (Price, Quantity) - note: "ITEM" is non-duplicated values . Thank you very much

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Number your rows in the breakout using `=1` and `=A1+1` and then just use the formula `="B-ITEM"&TEXT(A1,"000")`.  If you want to skip making a counter column you could use `="B-ITEM"&TEXT(ROW()-1,"000")` to just use the current row number (minus 1 or however many you need).

If your items aren't sequentially like that, but still unique, I would recommend adding counters on the original tab similar to what you have, which would let you quickly find the 5th A or 7th B, something that counts the previous instances of your current type, and then adds 1.  For Row 6 you could do `=COUNTIF(A$1:A5,A6)+1`.

Comment: I would just use `=A6&COUNTIF(A$1:A5,A6)+1` to create lookup values on your main sheet then that are Code and count appended together, and then use my first paragraph method above to look up CODE and count appended together.  You won't need the TEXT part, just ="A"&ROW()-1 or something like that.